# Bind to LDAP with other account and then search user with password in LDAP server

Tags: java, ldap, jaas

I have a service account by which i bind LDAP connection , i am using JAAS `LdapLoginModule` to authenticate the account. Once LDAP bind succeeds, I need to search or authenticate or search other normal user with its user name and password.

So how I am supposed to approach because i did not find any search query with password for user and LDAP bind permission is not allowed for this normal user. I am able to retrieve all the groups and users inside them but i could not find password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Bind to the directory as the admin user with permission to search.
2. Search for the user given whatever attribute you have that is unique, for example, screen name, email, etc.
3. Attempt to bind as that user with the password he supplied.

If all this succeeds, the user attribute and password were correct. If not, not.

Comment: I have bind permission for only master user and other normal user don't have bind permission which i need to validate with user name and password so is there any other way around

Comment: You've done it wrong, or whoever set up the LDAP server. This is how you are supposed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP directory in its "normal" way of using it as authentication provider do not allow any user to read the password attribute to avoid leaking it.

What it is normally done is to allow anybody to authenticate on this attribute only, ie : the attribute can be used by anybody to try a bind operation.

So 2 ways of dealing with your case :

1. [not recommended] : modify the access right to allow the user used to search to read the password attribute (=> create a possible security issue)
2. allow anonymous connection to only bind on the password attribute

EDIT : To answer question in comment :

As I stated previously, to compare and/or read (as in LDAP operation of the protocol) the password attribute of another user than your master account, you have to allow the master account to do it, but it is not recommended.

How to allow it, it depends of the LDAP implementation you use (ie. which directory : OpenLDAP, AD, ApacheDS, etc.)

Or you allow everyone to bind on the directory, which is the standart way of doing this :

- Bind with master password
- Search the DN of the user which try to bind
- Re-bind with the DN of the user and the password he provided :

  - Bind OK : correct password
  - Bind KO : invalid credential

Comment: I have successfully bind the user with password on master account by using JASS login but now i need to validate the user name and password of the user which is actually trying to login in LDAP server. Is there any way to compare the user password

Comment: @Shardendu I edited my answer with more informations ;)

Comment: we don't have bind permission for normal user , so can't bind through LDAP if i was able to bind the normal user than i don't think i need to bind by Master user. Is there any way to compare password and username of existng users

Comment: @Shardendu Well you *need* bind permissions for normal users. Otherwise your LDAP directory is completely useless. You don't need to compare passwords when the LDAP server can already do it for you. You *do* need to do the search as an admin user before binding as the real user. Your understanding is deeply flawed.

Comment: It is not in my hand to give bind permission to normal user . any other way around to achieve this. Because we can give bind permission to only Master user for security purpose

Comment: @Shardendu As I stated in my answer, according to your directory, you could be able to grant your master account the right to read and/or compare the password attribute.

Comment: @Shardendu `we can give bind permission to only Master user for security purpose` : Concerning this point, I could not disagree more. Giving read permission to your master account on all the password is far more dangerous than authorizing anybody to try a bind and no way of reading password content for anybody

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate only without any authorization using JAAS then do not use complete DN in security principle just pass the username like below. it will get authenticated but not authorized

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "passWord");
```

Like this if you want authorization then there is some other way